# Cant gain acces to url with role ADMIN spring security

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-security

I have a problem with spring security because i dont get a access to url with role admin when i am logged on site
this is mine security config

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder("53cr3t");
    }

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }




    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/rentAppPage/*").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/addVehicle").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/getVehicle").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/removeVehicle").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/updateVehicle").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/allUser").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/resultGet").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/addUser").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/getUser").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/updateUser").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/removeUserById").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/price").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/allScooter").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/allCar").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/allMotorBike").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/allBike").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/distance").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rent").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rent2").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/buy").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/buy2").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/thanks").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rentAppPage").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
        ;

        http.sessionManagement()
                //.expiredUrl("/sessionExpired.html")
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login.html");
    }
}
```

i trying with hasRole , hasAuthority ,hasAnyAuthority but dont work , only work permittAll but i dont want to access something url to user with role user
this is mine login controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Resource(name = "sessionObject")
    SessionObject sessionObject;

    @Autowired
    IAuthenticationService authenticationService;

    public LoginController(){

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String mainSite(){
        return "redirect:login";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("userModel",new User());
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage","");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  String authenticateUser(@ModelAttribute("userModel")User user,Model model){
        boolean authResult = this.authenticationService.authenticationUser(user);
        if(authResult){
            System.out.println("logged  !!");
            this.sessionObject.setUser(user);
            return "rentAppPage";
        }else{
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage","error data!!!");
            model.addAttribute("userModel",new User());
            return "login";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rentAppPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page(Model model) {
        if(this.sessionObject.getUser() == null) {
            return "redirect:/login";
        }

        model.addAttribute("username", this.sessionObject.getUser().getUsername());
        System.out.println(this.sessionObject.getUser().getUsername());
        return "rentAppPage";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/logout",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(){
        this.sessionObject.setUser(null);
        return "redirect:login";
    }
```

i have in database two users one with role Admin and second with role USER but this dont work
can someone explain why ?

[image]

https://github.com/Conrado1212/Electrical-Rent-App here is my fulll code

Comment: Can you show us how are exactly the Roles in Database stored ??

Comment: i edit now you can see i try ROLE_ADMIN but dont work and i change to ADMIN

Comment: you should store in database ROLE_ADMIN instead of ADMIN

Comment: ok i change to ROLE_ADMIN and i change antMatchers("/addVehicle/*").hasRole("ADMIN") but i dont know why i always return to login

Comment: i must login with generate password for spring security ?

Answer (score 0):

For sure following configuration is wrong

```
antMatchers("/rentAppPage/*").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
```

it should be

```
antMatchers("/rentAppPage/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Also, as a recommendation, try to be more consistent, you are mixing in your configuration hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") with hasRole("ADMIN") when both have the same meaning, stickt to one and make your code clearer.

Comment: Spring security gives its kind of login in the sense of login and password but i have my registration and login with my username and my password not generate, whether it has any impact authenticated () ?

Comment: i change to  ```.antMatchers("/").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/rentAppPage/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/addVehicle").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/getVehicle").hasRole("ADMIN")``` but dont work

Answer (score 0):

Bro it would have been much better if you would have send us the whole code to get the better understanding of your error. But I can tell you the alternative. You can check role in HTML only. For example you have button to add vehicle, you can only show and hide that button on the basis of role of user. In your case if you want to show that button to only admin then you can use it like this:

```
    <% if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin")){ %>
        //your add vehicle button
    <%}%>
```

Disclaimer: This is not an ideal solution but it will work.

If you are using thymeleaf you can do it this way:-

```
     <div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ADMIN'')')}">
       <li><a href="/addVehicle">Add Vehicle</a> </li>
     </div>
```

You will only be able to see this list if you are logged in as Admin otherwise not. If you want to test this instead of writing list tag use some HTML text instead like

```
      <div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ADMIN'')')}">
       <label>Hey, Admin only you can see me</label>
     </div>
```

Here only the user whose role is admin will be able to see this text.
Let me know if this works

Comment: https://github.com/Conrado1212/Electrical-Rent-App here is my full code but you must to create database or i can import you my database

Comment: i try to test this <% if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin")){ %>
                    <li><a href="/addVehicle">Add Vehicle</a> </li>
                    <%}%> but i dont know how this  can work

Comment: Ok, i have seen your repo and I have seen you are using thymeleaf so I am gonna edit the answer to add the thymeleaf code, and I will also tells you how it works using thymeleaf

Comment: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ADMIN'')')" (template: "rentAppPage" - line 25, col 14) when i try to test this by your label i get error

Comment: bro those are not double quotes, they are two separate single quotes like ' '

Comment: i know in my commment look like one " but i copy your div and i has this error Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ADMIN'')')" (template: "rentAppPage" - line 90, col 10)

Comment: maybe i havent something in my pom and this cant work ?

Comment: is there a nested exception as well or this is it?. and also check out this link https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-app-with-auth-example/issues/2

Comment: the exception start here ->th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ADMIN'')')

Comment: i add dependency and now is good but when i logged on my user with role admin i dont see this label. as if he did not see that my user has the role of admin , maybe my login controller is bad i dont know why i dont see this label

Comment: ok, now you are not seeing any error that's progress. Yeah, it is not authorizing as admin I guess. Try chnaging hasAuthority to hasRole in your security config

Comment: i change to hasRole in my securityConfig but dont still dont work . it looks like securityspring doesn't see the user's role or as if there is no authentication maybe in my user method getAuthorities is wrong ? it should work fine but it don't work

Comment: Okay, dont worry. How have you specified role in database. It should be like ROLE_ADMIN and in security config it should be like 'ADMIN' only.

Comment: And to check whether it is working or not debug these authorizations in controller also, just after login by printing it to the console.

Comment: i have in database role ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER and i check my method autenticateUser and i think this is bad maybe because when i use sout to print user which log in i have output with his username and password another field have null or 0.0 ?

Comment: Maybe i have bad method loadByusername ?

Comment: Then try to debug it in UserDetailsServiceImplementation. Check whether you are getting all user details from there or not.

Comment: i have one more question method loadUserByUsername i must use in login  or in other controller ?

Comment: i dont think thats the issue

Comment: it looks like i never go through authentication. Maybe my authentication service is invalid? and i need to do something else?

Comment: or maybe i dont have this but ``` @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }``` when i tried to add i have error on (userdetailsService)